# How to add data to additional column in pivot table in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to build an app in Laravel 5.3, I want to add additional column data in the pivot table. Following is my code:

My `Users` model:

```
public function relations()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Plan')->withPivot('child');
}
```

My `Plan` model:

```
public function relations()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('child');
}
```

In my controller I'm fetching the user data from `Auth::user();` and for plans and child element I'm getting through request. I want to store this to my pivot table. Following is the code which I tried in my controller:

```
$user = \Auth::user();
$plan_id = $request->plan_id;
$childid = $request->child_id;
$plan = App\Plan::find($plan_id);
$user->relations()->attach($plan, ['child' => $childid]);
```

Help me out in this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use [`attach()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) like this:

```
$user->relations()->attach($plan_id, ['child' => $childid]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the `save` method as:

```
$user->relations()->save($plan, ['child' => $childid]);
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Answer (score 3):

Both `save` and `attach` work. Just that `attach` will return null while `save` will return $user object when I try with tinker